# Accessing stdout or stdout_lines of ansible debug output

Tags: ansible

I want to access only stdout_lines or stdout output part (i.e, online) from below debug output log but I get whole log.

I just mentioned related code here:

code:

```
- debug: msg=" {{ item.stdout_lines }} "
    with_items: " {{ result.results }} "
```

## Output:

```
ok: [192.168.0.1] => (item={'changed': True, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'stdout': u'[online]\r\n', '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'process1', 'stderr': u'Shared connection to 192.168.154.241 closed.\r\n', 'rc': 0, 'stdout_lines': [u'[online]'], '_ansible_ignore_errors': None, 'failed': False}) => {
    "changed": false, 
    "item": {
        "changed": true, 
        "failed": false, 
        "item": "process1", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.0.1 closed.\r\n", 
        "stdout": "[online]\r\n", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "[online]"
        ]
    }, 
    "msg": " [u'[online]'] "
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like you are running ansible-playbook with the `-v` option.  So you are seeing more information because you are in verbose mode.

Also, since you are using `with_items` in your debug task you will see the contents of the current item displayed as that item is processed.  You can control what gets displayed for each item by using the [loop_control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control)

```
- debug: msg=" {{ item.stdout_lines }} "
    with_items: " {{ result.results }} "
  loop_control:
    label: '...'
```